# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python, tkinter

programm is working perfectly before defining the function problem is that it is not getting the value from the user input and showing it to me and then error is coming too.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



root = Tk()
root.title("Social Network - Login")

frame = ttk.Frame(root) #define new frame
frame.grid(row=2,column=1)
frame.config(height=200, width=200, relief=RIDGE, padding=(10,10))


l1 = ttk.Label(frame, text="User name").grid(row=0, column=0)

etUserName = ttk.Entry(frame, width=20).grid(row=0, column=1)

l2 = ttk.Label(frame, text="Password").grid(row=1,column=0)

etpassword = ttk.Entry(frame, width=20, show="*").grid(row=1, column=1)

buLogin = ttk.Button(frame,text="Login").grid(row=2,column=1)

def BuClick():
    print("Username: {},Password: {}".format(etUserName.get(),etpassword.get()))


buLogin.config(command=BuClick)

root.mainloop()
```

error is occuring here in config

```
buLogin.config(command=BuClick)
```

same questions which are already does not addressed my problem directly i checked the similar questions but couldn't able to find the answer that's why i post this question.

Comment: The `grid` method returns `None`, not `self`. So all those variables you created don't hold your labels and entries and so on, they hold `None`. So, when you call `buLogin.config`, you're trying to call the `config` method of `None`, not of a `Button`. Hence the error. You did this right with `frame`; you just have to do the same for your other widgets.

Comment: Ok tell me is it the right away to write the code, because it was compiling fine when i tried first time then problem occur afterwards

Comment: Remove the duplicate marked please because the similar question does not solve my problem thats why I post the question.

Comment: There are 4 duplicates marked. The second one's error is not just similar, but identical to yours, and the answer not only shows how to fix the code, but also explains the problem. There's further explanation, and examples, in the other three, that are all relevant as well.

Comment: Oh I see that now i didn't open that question because it wasn't green when i was searching for the question and the heading wasn't the same as mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to in this can be traced backed to this line

```
buLogin = ttk.Button(frame,text="Login").grid(row=2,column=1)
```

i think the .grid() is not returning anything. can you try like this

```
buLogin = ttk.Button(frame,text="Login")
buLogin.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

And ideally you should change all the usage of `grid()` like this.

This should work, I havn't tested this yet. please let us know the result.
Happy coding :)

Comment: Not only this line, but the same error is actually in almost all the lines and needs to be fixed in several places